# Copying a database JPA

Tags: java, database, jpa, copy

I have a working code that basically copies records from one database to another one using JPA. It works fine but it takes a while, so I wonder if there's any faster way to do this.

I thought Threads, but I get into race conditions and synchronizing those pieces of the code end up being as long as the one by one process.

Any ideas?

**Update**

Here's the scenario:

- Application (Core) has a database.
- Plugins have default data (same structure as Core, but with different data)
- When the plugin is enabled it checks in the Core database and if not found it copies from it's default data into the core database.

Answer (score 1):

Most databases provide native tools to support this. Unless you need to write additional custom logic to transform the data in some way, I would recommend looking at the export/import tools provided by your database vendor.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but since is targeted to JPA (as stated in the question) the target database can vary.

Comment: Are you building a tool that can support any database? If not, then I'd go with the easy approach and use the tools that are available to you, and not try to build them yourself.

Comment: Added more details on the scenario in hope it'll explain a bit more. I think copy might be misleading/confusing.